# Importing an Excel file, every column as specified field

Tags: feeds, importing-exporting

My installed modules: feeds , feeds_xls

My excel file is : books.xlxs (office 2007)

File sheets: my file have 15 sheets (this sheets must be as drupal taxonomy term)

Every sheets involve 6 column (this column and its contents must be as drupal field content)

I created a drupal content type with books name.

I have attached an image to this post. you can see it.

I want to import ecxel file into Drupal content.every row on this tables must import to drupal as a node) content).

books Excel file image - click here

I no have any taxonomy term and extra fields to my content type (book). if I should add fields to drupal content type please say me.

I want to have a book list on my drupal site that users can search on it. every row is a content and every column in file is one field.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! So far, you stated facts without asking any explicit question. What you are saying is similar to "I want to make a cheesecake New York style." Users should not need to guess what you need to know. What did you try? What documentation or tutorials did you read? What didn't you understand in what you read? What exactly aren't able to do?

Comment: Also, you need to tell us your Drupal version, as what works for D8 *may* not work for D7 and vise versa.